# Any way to restrict a jar to make socket calls?

Tags: java, jar, classloader, java-security

We have a jar file which is getting loaded at runtime from internal server via http. It is done using custom URLClassLoader.

For security reason, we want to ensure that any code in that jar file does not make any http or socket connection outside of jvm.

Signing the jar is an option but it still does not prevent this from internal developer (unintentionally or intentionally)

Comment: If you're going to load unknown code you should use a SecurityManager to control it. That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: I imagine you could just override the [getPermissions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureClassLoader.html#getPermissions%28java.security.CodeSource%29) method of your custom ClassLoader.